# Is there a way using angular ui router not show #!/login?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I call `$state.go('login')` using Angular ui router, the suburl looks like this.

[image]

Is there a way to hide `#!/login`? It's first time to use angular ui router and I dont know even it's possible.
So I want to see only `localhost:3000/`

Comment: Set your "login" state to use the `/` URL? Ie, `url: ''`

Comment: search/read more about `angular html5 mode`

Comment: @harishr I don't think that applies here

Comment: @Phil yes you are right, its url change as you pointed out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a state without an url in `ui-router`, by simply not defining the url property when configuring your states.

Like this:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        component: 'loginComponent'
    });
});
```

You wont be able to navigate directly to the login url. But you'll still be able to use `ui-sref` or `$state.go('login')` to navigate.

---

If you still want to be able to navigate directly to the login page, you can configure another login state in addition to the above, where you specify the url property.

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        component: 'loginComponent'
    }).state('loginDirect', {
        url: '/login',
        component: 'loginComponent'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your config file:

`$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');`

For e.g.

```
angular.module('myPageApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app',{
       url: '/app',
       templateUrl: 'someView.html',
       controller: 'appController'
    })
    ... 
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your suggestion convert `#!/login` to `#/login` only removed `!` in the url.

Answer (score 0):

In above code, you can omit # and ! signs but can't skip the routed state in the URL. You can get the URL as localhost:3000/login or you can set the route on '/' identifier.

If your application does not use HTML5 mode or is being run on browsers that do not support HTML5 mode, and you have not specified your own hash-prefix then client side URLs will now contain a ! prefix.

To make your HTML5 mode ON, try following code.

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); // by default '!'
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Also in your header section of HTML, add this Base ref type as below:

```
<head>
    ...
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

For more information, kindly refer this code application here: https://github.com/TheAjinkya/Angular-UI-Router

Hope its helpful!